# How to send information from RFID-RC522 module to android phone via NFC?

Tags: android, arduino, nfc, sensors, rfid

I'm trying to send temperature and humidity data using arduino to a android smartphone via NFC. I set up the circuit using a DHT11 sensor to measure data, and RFID-RC522 module to read data when using an identified tag. I want to be able to see the data from the phone, when I read my NFC supported phone to the module.

I ask for your help in this matter.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the MFRC522 chip is extremely basic and can only act as a reader, thus probably your only option is to use [Host Card Emulation (HCE) on Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce) so that the Android phone emulates a Type 4 (ISO 7816) Tag.

But you will still have to do a lot of work on the Arduino to implement the the protocols needed, to have the MFRC522 to write data to the Android phone pretending to be a Tag.

If you used a more advanced NFC Chip like the PN532 you could reverse the roles and as the PN532 can emulate a Tag and thus the Android Phone could be the reader and just read values from the PN532 emulated Tag

Note I've not tried this myself, just my research in to a similar problem.